# Interpolate between two columns of a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, interpolation

I am attempting to interpolate a value based on a number's position in a different column. Take this column for instance:

```
Coupon  Price
9.5     109.04
9.375   108.79
9.25    108.54
9.125   108.29
9       108.04
8.875   107.79
8.75    107.54
8.625   107.29
8.5     107.04
8.375   106.79
8.25    106.54
```

Lets say I have a number like 107. I want to be able to find 107's relative distance from both 107.04 and 106.79 to interpolate the value that has the same relative distance between 8.5 and 8.375, the coupon values at the same index. Is this possible? I can solve this in excel using the FORECAST method, but want to know if it can be done in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

We need to make a custom function for this, unless there's a standard library function I'm unaware, which is entirely possible. I'm going to make a function that allows you to enter a bond by price and it will get inserted into the dataframe with the appropriate coupon.

Assuming we are starting with a sorted dataframe.

```
print(df)

    Coupon   Price
0    9.500  109.04
1    9.375  108.79
2    9.250  108.54
3    9.125  108.29
4    9.000  108.04
5    8.875  107.79
6    8.750  107.54
7    8.625  107.29
8    8.500  107.04
9    8.375  106.79
10   8.250  106.54
```

I've inserted comments into the function.

```
def add_bond(Price, df):
    # Add row
    df.loc[df.shape[0]] = [np.NaN, Price]
    df = df.sort_values('Price', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Get index
    idx = df[df['Price'] == Price].head(1).index.tolist()[0]

    # Get the distance from Prices from previous row to next row
    span = abs(df.iloc[idx-1, 1] - df.iloc[idx +1, 1]).round(4)

    # Get the distance and direction from Price from previous row to new value
    terp = (df.iloc[idx, 1] - df.iloc[idx-1, 1]).round(4)

    # Find the percentage movement from previous in percentage.
    moved = terp / span

    # Finally calculate the move from the previous for Coupon.
    df.iloc[idx, 0] = df.iloc[idx-1,0] + (abs(df.iloc[idx-1,0] - df.iloc[idx+1, 0]) * (moved))

    return df
```

A function to calculate the Coupon of a new bond using Price in the DataFrame.

```
# Add 107
df =  add_bond(107, df)
print(df)

    Coupon   Price
0    9.500  109.04
1    9.375  108.79
2    9.250  108.54
3    9.125  108.29
4    9.000  108.04
5    8.875  107.79
6    8.750  107.54
7    8.625  107.29
8    8.500  107.04
9    8.480  107.00
10   8.375  106.79
11   8.250  106.54
```

Add one more.

```
# Add 107.9
df = add_bond(107.9, df)
print(df)

    Coupon   Price
0    9.500  109.04
1    9.375  108.79
2    9.250  108.54
3    9.125  108.29
4    9.000  108.04
5    8.930  107.90
6    8.875  107.79
7    8.750  107.54
8    8.625  107.29
9    8.500  107.04
10   8.480  107.00
11   8.375  106.79
12   8.250  106.54
```

If this answer meets your needs, please remember to select correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a function that does the work for you somewhere but my advice is to program it yourself, it's not difficult at all and it's a nice programming excercise. Just find the slope in that segment and use the equation a straight line:

```
(y-y0) = ((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))*(x-x0) -> y = ((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))*(x-x0) + y0

Where:

x -> Your given value (107)
x1 & x0 -> The values right above and below (107.04 & 106.79)
y1 & y0 -> The corresponding values to x1 & x0 (8.5 & 8.375)
y -> Your target value.
```

Just basic high-school maths ;-)